# Grignard Reaction with Unsaturated Methyl Ester | Prevention of Acid Catalyzed Hydration

Tags: organic-chemistry

I am attempting to perform a Grignard reaction involving methyl 3-butenoate and methyl magnesium iodide in order to yield the unsaturated tertiary alcohol 2-methyl-4-penten-2-ol. The issue in doing this is that conditions are involved in the acidic workup of the bromomagnesium alkoxide the would also result in the acid-catalyzed hydration of the double bond (cold conditions). I am wondering if it is possible to replace the ice/sulfuric acid acidic workup with a solution of 3 M sulphuric acid in methanol, on an ice bath of course? Firstly, would this prevent the acid-catalyzed hydration of my double bond since no water is present? Also, would this prevent the acid-catalyzed dehydration of my newly formed tertiary alcohol since the conditions are cold (however, the fact there is no water, may result in forcing equilibrium concentrations, so would I have to keep the reaction at VERY low temperature like -78 C?). Secondly, If this would reaction would theoretically work, is there any literature available of anyone attempting it, I have searched and am not able to find any, also would methyl alcohol be the best choice in this case since it will be easy to rotovap in future steps? I will include the procedure I am looking to modify below along with a general scheme for my reaction (I have modified the procedure from Vogel's textobook of Practical Organic Chemistry page 540):

> Prepare an ether solution of methylmagnesium iodide from 12.687 g (522.0 mmol) of dry magnesium turnings, 74.093g (32.5 mL, 522.0 mmoles) of dry methyl iodide and 104.4 mL of sodium-dried ether; use the apparatus and procedure described in Exp 5.39, cognate preparation nonan-1-ol. Allow to cool (ice bath), and slowly add a solution of 26.66 g (261 mmol) of A in 26.1 mL of anhydrous ether into the vigorously stirred solution of the Grignard reagent. Reflux the mixture on a water bath for 1 hour to complete the reaction. **Pour the ethereal solution into a mixture of 52.2 mL of approximately 2 M sulphuric acid and 196 g of crushed ice.** Separate the upper ethereal layer and extract the aqueous solution with two 39.2 mL portions of ether. Wash the combined ethereal extracts with dilute sodium hydrogen carbonate solution, followed by a little water, then dry with anhydrous potassium carbonate or anhydrous calcium sulfate, distill off the ether on a water bath and distill the residue through a short fractionating column. Collect at 117-120 C. A further small quantity of the tertiary alcohol may be obtained by redrying the low-boiling distillate, filtering and redistilling. The yield is 90 g (88%).

[image]

Comment: I usually work up my Grignrds by slow addition of cold aq NH4Cl soln. You do not need to work up with strong acid to get rid of the Mg salts.